# Why my own mymax function (replacement of python built-in max) cannot compare strings properly?

Tags: python, function

I am writing mymax() function as a replacement of python in-built max function. mymax will be universal function - can take any iterable (list, tuple, string) and returns the largest element in the iterable.  While this works totally fine for list and tuple, it is inconsistent while returning the larger string.

-- The following function returns 'lives in Jungles' as larger element which is incorrect.

```
def mymax(seq):
    #for loop to initiate var as emtpy string or as 0 depending on user input.
    for elemType in seq:
        if isinstance(elemType, str):
            var = ''
            break
        else:
            var = 0
    # for loop to find the largest element in the sequence.
    for element in seq:
        if element > var:  
            var = element
    return var
    
mymax(('Lions', 'live in Jungles', 'and under the starry sky'))
   -- this return 'live in Jungles' although 3rd element is larger.

mymax(('Lions', 'live in Jungles', 'and under the starry sky', 'within this galaxy where earth revolves around the sun.'))
  -- rightly returns the 4th element
```

What could be causing this inconsistency?

I tried to different arguments to mymax function but it still seems to be behaving inconsistently with list of strings.

Comment: You are wrong.  "live in Jungles" is greater than "and under the starry sky" because the letter "l" comes after the letter "a".  If you want to compare the LENGTHS, then you need different code.

Comment: By the way, how will you handle `mymax(["abc", [1,"a",3], (None,42)])`?  What you're doing seems pointless.

Comment: Python compares strings by alphabetical order, so `'xy' > 'abcdef'` is `True`

Answer (score 2):

When you compare strings using the `>` operator, it compares them character by character according to their Unicode code points. To fix this issue and make your `mymax` function work consistently across different types of iterables including strings:

```
def mymax(seq):
# Initialize var as the first element of the sequence
    var = seq[0] if seq else None

# Iterate through the sequence
    for element in seq:
    # Compare based on types
        if isinstance(var, str) and isinstance(element, str):
            if len(element) > len(var):
                var = element
        elif element > var:
            var = element

    return var
    
print(mymax(('Lions', 'live in Jungles', 'and under the starry sky')))  

print(mymax(('Lions', 'live in Jungles', 'and under the starry sky', 'within this galaxy where earth revolves around the sun.')))
```

Output:

```
and under the starry sky
within this galaxy where earth revolves around the sun.
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, max() operates on the sort order of the objects passed to it. In the case of strings, the sort order is determine by lexicographical comparison. Your concept of "largest" is flawed. You could, of course, pass a key parameter to the built-in max() function which would then match your idea of "largest" in the context of strings.

So, if you want to emulate the built-in *max()* function, you could do this:

```
def mymax(seq, key=None):
    return sorted(seq, key=key)[-1]
```

...then...

```
sentences = [
    "Give every man thy ear, but few thy voice",
    "What's done can't be undone",
    "Though she be but little, she is fierce"
    ]

print(mymax(sentences))
print(mymax(sentences, key=len))
```

**Output:**

```
What's done can't be undone
Give every man thy ear, but few thy voice
```